# Exporting Sentinel 2 image to drive error

Tags: google-earth-engine

While exporting Sentinel 2 image to drive I am getting this error:

```
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': 
Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. 
Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)
```

Code:

```js
// This is the Sentinel-2 collection (all the possible available Sentinel 2 imagery)
var S2_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2").filterBounds(roi);

// These are the bands that we want to be displayed
var S2_bands = ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'];

// This turns the whole S2 collection into one image, finding the middle value for each pixel
var S2_mosaic = S2_collection.median().select(S2_bands).clip(roi);

// This controls how we want the S2 image to be displayed
var S2_display = {bands: S2_bands, min: 0, max: 3000};

// This adds the S2_mosaic to the map, using the S2_display visual parameters, and giving it the name "S2_Image"
Map.addLayer(S2_mosaic, S2_display, "S2_Image");

// This automatically pans the map to the middle of our Sentinel-2 image
Map.centerObject(roi);

// Export.image.toDrive({
//   image: S2_collection,
//   description: 'sentbang',
//   scale: 10,
//   region: roi,
//   maxPixels: 1e13
// });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem. You are trying to export an `ImageCollection` i.e a collection of multiple images, when the `Export.image.toDrive` function is expecting a single `Image`.

Perhaps you meant to export the `S2_mosaic` image that you created?

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: S2_mosaic,
  description: 'sentbang',
  scale: 10,
  region: roi,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```